# Frustration using rJava to call a third party Java jar

Tags: r, rjava

I'm trying to use R to hook the Java code from the GSRad project. The GSRad Java code is [available online](http://www.sipeaa.it/ASP/ASP2/GSRad.asp) and comes as a [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=quickstart) project jar (I was not familiar with One-Jar until today). I can run the One-Jar file just dandy using the following command (after unzipping the file from the above link):

```
 java -jar gsrad_sample.jar
```

When I pop open the gsrad_sample.jar file I see a jar titled clima_GSRAD-1.0.0.jar in the /lib/ directory which contains the class files I want to hook with R. I've pulled out the jar of my affection and tried the following, to no avail:

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
.jaddClassPath( "/home/jal/Documents/DSSAT/gsrad/clima_GSRAD-1.0.0.jar" )
.jnew( "cra/clima/gsrad/GSRBristowCampbellStrategy" )
```

Any tips on how I might hook the classes inside the clima_GSRAD-1.0.0.jar? I'm flummoxed.

**EDIT**

The GSRad site requires registration which is annoying. The full zip file which contains the Doxygen documentation for the Java package as well as the One-Jar jar file is available [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/79688/gsrad/gsrad_install_Java.zip) and if you pop that open the jar that has the classes I want to hook is [this one](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/79688/gsrad/clima_GSRAD-1.0.0.jar).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me preface my answer by saying that I'm no expert in Java / rJava, so apologies if this isn't 100% correct.  I hope it's a step in the right direction though.

Start by unzipping `gsrad_sample.jar` to `C:/gsrad` (or adjust your paths based on where you unzip it).  Then add *all* the contents of `C:/gsrad/lib` to your class path:

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
.jaddClassPath(dir( "C:/gsrad/lib", full.names=TRUE ))
.jclassPath()
.jnew( "cra/clima/gsrad/GSRBristowCampbellStrategy" )
```

Comment: I wish I could learn something from this other than, "try adding a higher branch to the classpath when things don't work." Classpaths seem like mysterious incantations to me.

Comment: @JD Long: it could also be that the class you wanted to use depended on classes in those other jar files.

Comment: that's my suspicion as well. But it leaves me with the nagging question, "how could I have known that... except through trial and error?"